# how to remove %20%20%20 in url before pass in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

```
<a href="CardslistErdem.aspx?Number=<%#Eval("Number")%>&Albom=<%#Eval("Albom")%>"  class="fa fa-search-plus"></a>
```

and after call it will be

http://localhost:7258/Azhar%203/CardslistErdem.aspxNumber=50541%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&Albom=Erdem

so i need to be as

http://localhost:7258/Azhar%203/CardslistErdem.aspxNumber=50541&Albom=Erdem

Without space ....please help me

Comment: Try `<%#Eval("Number").ToString().Trim()%>`

Comment: @MethodMan UrlDecode will just give him a bunch of spaces after Number = 50541 from what he's asking for it looks like he doesn't even want it decoded he wants din's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your parameter values may contain spaces. That should be easy to remove with `Trim`:

```
<%# Eval("Number").ToString().Trim() %>
```

likewise

```
<%# Eval("Albom").ToString().Trim() %>
```

One thing to be aware of is null values, which you may need to check for. If you are using latest version of C# (6.0), this is super easy with null conditional operator:

```
<%# Eval("Number")?.ToString().Trim() %>
```